# Windows unkillable process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-8, admin, exe

For the last several weeks, I have been making a parental controls program (just for my friend and myself), in Python (it's what I know). I used CX_Freeze to get the `.exe`, and it works wonderfully. Everything is great... But I need a way to make the process unkillable to standard users. (*just* standard users. I want admins to be able to kill this easily if need be.)

I was pursuing a method in which my `.exe` was turned into a windows service, thereby making it "SYSTEM" and unkillable to standard users. So far, the service cannot kill a process by using `taskkill /im`, and cannot create required setup `.txt` files.

Since that method appears to be failing, I thought I would ask if anyone knows of a way to make a process untouchable to standard users? I'm not entirely sure what professional parental controls/keyloggers/virus protection software uses to keep the user from killing the process, but perhaps something like that?

Comment: For anyone interested, check this similar question on the Security SE 
 https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/create-a-unterminable-process-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Making it a service is probably the right way to go - because it is the best way to automatically launch a process with some admin rights.

I think the reason that your service wasn't able to kill other processes was due to the account used to run the service under.

A service can run as system, local service, network service, or a specified account/password.
The idea here is to limit services to just be allowed to access what they need. A 'network service' service has very little access to local resources, while "local service" won't have network access. MSDN has all the details.

I don't remember offhand the details of exactly how you specify this during service registration, but I think it is pretty straightforward.

You will notice also that there is a checkbox for "Allow service to interact with the desktop".
Normally you don't want a service to directly control any UI because a UI is very hard to defend from attack - other processes could send messages which cause mischief in the service - potentially allowing them to hack the system.

I think that for your purposes, using a specific login for an admin account will suffice.
In "services.msc", it is simple enough to select your service, and enter a username/password for the service to run in.

Comment: Well, running it under my admin account did not work. It still could not create required files, or kill unwanted processes. I believe what's happening, is that NSSM is running my `.exe` in the `system32` folder. Is there any way to make NSSM run it where the file is located?

Comment: It works fine when I run it manually, but then anyone can kill it. Like I said, I think somehow NSSM is pulling the `.exe` to `System32`, although I don't know why. (When I used the cmd prompt to start it, it could open new txt docs, but it was trying to put them in system32)

Comment: Running  "in system32":  You mean that system32 is the current-directory? Your process can change that just like running "CD" at a command prompt. This would only affect local file paths, not anything about the kill-ability of the process. (You could also use absolute paths for your *.txt files: "C:\foo\MyLog.txt" instead of "MyLog.txt". What errors does it get when trying to kill other processes?

Comment: Well, if it cannot find the list of forbidden processes, perhaps it cannot kill?

Comment: I just made my win service point at a batch file that opens notepad.exe if it's not already open. Again, works well when run manually, but doesn't do anything when run by system. I'll try making the service use local user though. ** Making the service run as local user seems to keep a process of notepad.exe open... But without an GUI. Odd.

Comment: Okay, I modified the `.bat` pointer, nd set it to start my `.exe` as local user. It appears to be working, but cannot open webpages or load the notepad.exe GUI. (Not opening the html windows it needs, and while it starts notepad.exe, I can see no GUI.) I guess I'm back to my original though that it does not work because services cannot interact with desktop?

Comment: Note that checkbox in "Services.msc" "Allow Service to interact with the desktop".

Comment: Read this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note that there is a global windows setting which will prevent any service from creating a UI. The default setting varies by OS version. Also take a look at WindowStations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, that checkbox does nothing for me. I tried, and it works the same as before.

Comment: Also, since I am using python not c++ I cannot use the c++ workaround you mentioned without converting my code.

Answer (score 0):

So, I know this question is like 5 years old, but you can make it actually kinda unkillable to even the admin. Make the program run as admin, so only admins can kill it. Then, make a loop that kills consent.exe constantly (consent.exe is the UAC pop-up). To kill the process, you need to be an admin, but you can't be an admin, because you can't accept the UAC prompt. But there is a catch. If you disable UAC via UAC settings, you can become an admin and kill the process. This can be used as a kind of failsafe.